# WPF, set DataContext to property of same class

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, blend

I have a class `Device` that uses the `INotifyPropertyChanged`, it is tested and it works.

Now I have a `deviceMonitor` that is the UI representation of this device. In the code I have a reference to `Device` and I want to link changes in the device to changes in the UI (two way is not needed, but clicking the `deviceMonitor` should call a certain function of the `device`)

I'm using expression Blend with VS2015 so guidance based on where to click to get it to work would be extremely welcome.

this is a mockup of the `device`

```
public class Device : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { ... } //uses NotifyPropertyChanged in the set
    // other properties and their relative private vars.
}
```

Then the xaml.cs for the GUI, here I have a reference to the dll containing the `Device`:

```
public partial class DeviceControl : UserControl
{
   public Device myDevice = new Device();

   public DeviceControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // here I tried setting the datacontest to the myDevice

        // also tried to set the dataContext in Blend and here grab a
        // reference to it and store it in myDevice. But nothing workerd
    }

    public void ChangeDevName()
    {
         this.myDevice.DeviceName = "Test";
         //UI Representation of deviceName never changed
    }
}
```

Then the XAML

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <recoveriX:RecoverixDevice  DeviceName="thisIsAName"/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="title"  Text="{Binding DeviceName}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

In your `DeviceControl` UserControl, wire up events for `OnLoaded` and `OnUnloaded` of the control.

In the code-behind for the event handlers, subscribe/unsubscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event of UserControl's DataContext (`this.DataContext`) ; like so:

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.DataContext is INotifyPropertyChanged)
    {
        ((INotifyPropertyChanged)this.DataContext).PropertyChanged += OnDataContextPropertyChanged;
    }
}

private void OnUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.DataContext is INotifyPropertyChanged)
    {
        ((INotifyPropertyChanged)this.DataContext).PropertyChanged -= OnDataContextPropertyChanged;
    }
}

private void OnDataContextPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // You could also just update every time something is changed.
    // As an example you could check for the "Name" property being changed.
    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Device.Name))
    {
        title.Text = this.DataContext.Name;
    }
}
```

An important note to make is the `if (this.myDevice is INotifyPropertyChanged)` check.

It ensures the `Device` class inherits from `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Providing it does, it casts the `Device` being your DataContext (`this.DataContext`) to `(INotifyPropertyChanged)` so you can subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event from the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Then, when a property on the `DataContext` is changed, your handler will be fired. Obviously you can put what you want to do in the code of `OnMyDevicePropertyChanged`, I've just used "Name" as an example.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**
Furthermore; you could also store a private field of type `Device` in the UserControl's code-behind. A bit like so:

```
private Device _viewModel; // You could also use the interface (like 'IDevice'), too.
```

Then in your `OnLoaded' event, store it in the field:

```
if (this.DataContext is INotifyPropertyChanged)
{
    this.viewModel = this.DataContext;

    // Wire up your PropertyChanged handler as before.
}
```

And on your `OnUnloaded` event, just unsubscribe from the viewModel if it is not null:

```
if (this.viewModel != null)
{
    this.viewModel.PropertyChanged -= OnDataContextPropertyChanged;
}
```

This also gives you a bit more flexibility when you've got the DataContext stored as a field, as you can use it within other methods (if you use any more in your code behind - **you shouldn't...**; but it saves CPU time casting it to INotifyPropertyChanged all the time.

For future reference I would look at [Implementing MVVM Practices](https://blog.rsuter.com/recommendations-best-practices-implementing-mvvm-xaml-net-applications/) into your projects.

Good luck!

Comment: I totally agree with the MVVM practices, I've it in my todo list ... have been there for too long :(  Btw, check my answer because it worked without all this code you wrote and I don't exactly know why xD

Comment: It's because you're instantiating a new `Device` in the private field, and then setting the `DataContext` in your ctor... That's the **same** as what your Xaml is doing (as you'd set the DataContext in there, too). Make sure you do either/or, _NOT_ both. What I'm not sure about is how your `SetDevice()` method is getting called - hence wiring up the `PropertyChanged` in the loaded/unloaded.

Comment: **MORE** - just realised your `Binding` in Xaml would be using the property from the `Device`; thus getting `PropertyChanged` called and updating the `TextBlock`. There is no need for your `SetDevice()` method anymore.

Comment: I use the SetDevice method to change the attached device at run time so I can reuse the control. I´d like to keep both the this.DataContext and the _device  as private stuff and expose clear methods. Thanks for all those details, it is super interesting

Comment: Ah, I didn't know where your `SetDevice()` came into play. I've edited your own answer with some helpful tips. The long and short of all this, though; I must stress - is you could **really** do with not having the hassle of this in the first place and use MVVM *smug face*. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was overwriting the private device, setting the datacontext fixed the thing.
This is the final class:

```
public partial class DeviceControl : UserControl

private Device _device = new Device();

public DeviceControl()
{
    InitializeComponnents();
    this.DataContext = _device;
}

public void SetDevice(Device d)
{
    //This fails:
    //_device = d;

    //This works
    this.DataContext = d;
 }
```